# Sending a message between two separate applications

Tags: c++, winapi, message-queue

Hi,

I'm relatively new to c++ and software development in general, so I hope I can explain clearly my question.

I need two apps, one that listens the keyboard for a combo key press, and one that executes a function when that combo was pressed. I can't make them in a single app, because I'm trying to build something that resembles a kyosk, that when launched, starts *a new desktop* with limited functionality, and when a combo is detected, the original desktop is switched back. So, what I did, is launch this keyboard hook in the new desktop using `CreateProcess`, launch a new *explorer.exe* using the same function and switch to the new desktop.

I was doing some reading about *Messages* and *Message Queues* and I found out that this is a way to communicate between threads. So I was wondering if I could create my own Queue, put a message there at the combo key press, and periodically interogate this queue from another process, to make the necessary changes. If possible, could you post a link, or a code sample.

Thanks

Comment: Carefully reconsider if you really need two separate applications. From what you describe, I can see that a single keyboard listening application is enough. And don't confuse processes with threads.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/win32/article.php/c7401/Inter-Process-Communication-with-Registered-Windows-Messages.htm. That's the technique I used to communicate between a custom visualization and some bespoke hardware handling.